# Funcion que muestra la distancia entre dos número-R

Tags: r, function

Quiero crear una función en R que dado un intervalo de números (a, b) muestre lo siguiente.

1.Un número aleatorio del intervalo

2.La distancia del valor aleatorio al extremo "a" del intervalo.

3.La distancia del valor aleatorio al extremo "b" del intervalo.

Para ello primero considere lo siguiente

```
Interval<-function(a,b){
  Random_number<-sample(a:b, 1, replace=FALSE)
  return(Random_number)
}
Interval(a,b)
```

Hasta aquí genero sin problema el número aleatorio, sin embargo no sé cómo puedo expresar la diferencia.
Supongo que para intentar expresar la diferencia entre el número aleatorio debería utilizar el valor absoluto de la diferencia entre los dos números, sin embargo, ¿cómo "llamo" a estos números y poder operar entre ellos?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez algo como esto:

```
Interval<-function(a,b){
  rnd <- sample(a:b, 1)
  c(random_number = rnd, 
    dist_a = abs(rnd - a),
    dist_b = abs(rnd - b))
}

set.seed(2022)
Interval(1,10)

random_number        dist_a        dist_b 
            4             3             6
```

Notas:

- Debes guardar en una variable el número aleatorio para usarlo luego (`rnd`)
- Como ya has mencionado la diferencia es el `abs` de la diferencia entre `rnd` y cada límite
- Finalmente retornamos un vector con los tres datos, no es necesario el `return` explícito, por defecto R retorna el valor de la última expresión de la función.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código puede ayudarte. Modifique tu función para que regrese no solo el valor aleatorio sino también los valores extremos del intervalo.

```
Interval<-function(a,b){
  #creanis un vector con a y b para auxiliarnos
  v <- c(a,b)
  r<-sample(a:b, 1, replace=FALSE)
  # Creamos un vector de salida que contenga los valores a, b y r
  #He ordenado los dtos para que los preseente de mayor a menor (aqui es donde usamos v)
  int <- c(m = min(v), Random_number =r, M = max(v))
  return(int)
}

# Ahora podemos gurdar el resultado de la funcion intervalo en un objeto
intervalo1 <-Interval(1,10)
intervalo1 #Mostramos el contenido
intervalo1[1] #Los puedes ver 1 por uno
intervalo1[2]
intervalo1[3]
intervalo1[2]-intervalo1[1] #Y usarlos para calcular la distancia manualmente

#La funcion diff en R te da la distancia
diff(intervalo1)
```

También podrías guardar a las distancias en un vector y después llamarlas llamarlas una a una con  `[]`

```
dist<-diff(intervalo1)
dist[1]
dist[2]
```